# How can I visualize the activation map in conv layers?

Tags: theano, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'd like to visualize the activation map of caffe's convolutional
layers like this.(pic comes from this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07415)
[image]

And I've read the post of [net_surgery](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) in caffe's example. Since I've known how to get the activation map of the fc layer by change the fc layer to conv layer. But I don't know how to visualize the activation map in the middle conv layers. Can someone give me some suggestions? And it would be better if there is a script or toolbox that can do this. Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb) may be what you need.